# How to go back to original Sub Procedure from Key Down Event (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, events, onkeydown

I am trying to reference the KeyDown event from a independent sub procedure and have it loop back into original independent sub procedure.

1. Starts off in Independent sub procedure (DisplayAction - which then calls KeyDown Event)
2. Goes into KeyDown event (KeyDown then calls DisplayAction)
3. Goes back into original sub procedure (DisplayAction)  and the loop continues.

*** Steps 1 and 2 work just fine in my code. Step 3 is the problem. My program does not loop back into the independent sub procedure.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer
    Dim RandomNumbers(1000) As Integer
    Dim intAction As Integer
    Dim strAction1 As String = "A"
    Dim strAction2 As String = "B"
    Dim strAction3 As String = "C"
    Dim strAction4 As String = "D"
    Dim i As Integer

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        FormLoad(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormLoad(sender, e)

    'Creates random numbers here                    
        DisplayAction(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisplayAction(sender, e)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 3
            Select Case lstRandom.Items(i)
                Case 1
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction1
                    intAction = 1
                    frmMain_KeyDown(Sender, intAction = 1)
                Case 2
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction2
                    intAction = 2
                    frmMain_KeyDown(sender, intAction = 2)
                Case 3
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction3
                    intAction = 3
                    frmMain_KeyDown(sender, intAction = 3)
                Case 4
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction4
                    intAction = 4
                    frmMain_KeyDown(sender, intAction = 4)
            End Select
        Next i

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(sender, e) Handles Me.KeyDown


        If intAction = 1 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "works! 1"
            Call DisplayAction(sender, e)

        ElseIf intAction = 2 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "works! 2"
            Call DisplayAction(sender, e)

        ElseIf intAction = 3 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "works! 3"
            DisplayAction(sender, e)

        ElseIf intAction = 4 Then
            lblDisplay.Text = "works! 4"
            DisplayAction(sender, e)

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

It's automatic! When you call another method, and said method finished executing, *control is automatically returned to the caller*. Also, stop throwing around `sender` and `e`, and *please* turn `Option Strict On`.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer
    Dim RandomNumbers(1000) As Integer
    Dim intAction As Integer
    Dim strAction1 As String = "A"
    Dim strAction2 As String = "B"
    Dim strAction3 As String = "C"
    Dim strAction4 As String = "D"

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        FormLoad()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormLoad()
        'Creates random numbers here                    
        DisplayAction()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisplayAction()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 3
            Select Case lstRandom.Items(i)
                Case 1
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction1
                    intAction = 1
                    frmMain_KeyDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
                Case 2
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction2
                    intAction = 2
                    frmMain_KeyDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
                Case 3
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction3
                    intAction = 3
                    frmMain_KeyDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
                Case 4
                    lblDisplay.Text = strAction4
                    intAction = 4
                    frmMain_KeyDown(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End Select
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        lblDisplay.Text = "works! " & intAction
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: +1. Also, if you *never* want the event arguments, you can just leave them off to simplify the method signatures. Private Sub frmMain_Load() Handles Me.Load.  and Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown() Handles Me.KeyDown